# Missing solutions for complex equation system

Tags: equation-solving

I am currently working on a game-theoretic paper and trying to match two complex best response functions. The equation system includes two decision variables `x` and `y`, for which I want to find all possible solutions, and two static parameters `b` and `t`. The best response functions are given by

```
x == 1/18 (-6 b - t + 12 y + Sqrt[t] Sqrt[12 b + t + 12 y]
```

and

```
y == 1/18 (-6 b + t + 12 x - Sqrt[t] Sqrt[-12 b + t - 12 x])
```

Using

```
Solve[x == 1/18 (-6 b - t + 12 y + Sqrt[t] Sqrt[12 b + t + 12 y]) && 
      y == 1/18 (-6 b + t + 12 x - Sqrt[t] Sqrt[-12 b + t - 12 x]), {x, y}]
```

yields:

> ```
> {{x -> -b, y -> -b}, {x -> 1/25 (-25 b - 2 t), y -> 1/225 (-225 b - 17 t)}}
> ```

I also tried the `Reduce` command with the same result. Working on, two problems occurred.

**Problem 1: Checking results**

I wanted to double check my results and therefore replaced `x` and `y` in both equations above with

```
x = 1/25 (-25 b - 2 t) 
y = 1/225 (-225 b - 17 t)
```

and used the `Simplify` command, to see whether the results hold true. While this was the case for the first equation, simplifying the second equation yielded

> t==0.

Thus, the solution seems valid only for `t = 0`, though I expected `Solve` to give me generic solutions for any value of `t` (in fact, in my model `t > 0`).

**Problem 2: Further solutions**

I also inverted the second equation using

```
Solve[y == 1/18 (-6 b + t + 12 x - Sqrt[t] Sqrt[-12 b + t - 12 x]), x]
```

which yielded

> ```
> x == 1/8 (4 b - t + 12 y - Sqrt[t] Sqrt[-8 b + t - 8 y])
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> x == 1/8 (4 b - t + 12 y + Sqrt[t] Sqrt[-8 b + t - 8 y])
> ```

Solving the equation system as before but using the inverted form of the second equation yielded different results

> ```
> {{x -> -b, y -> -b}, {x -> 1/225 (-225 b + 17 t), y -> 1/25 (-25 b + 2 t)}
> ```

Again, I tried to check these results by inserting them into both equations, with the same result as before: `True` for the first equation but `t==0` for the second one.

Therefore my overall question is:

How can I get all possible and reliable solutions for the equation system above?

Comment: Seems to be due to a weak spot in the solution verifier when parameters and radicals are both present. Will have a closer look.

Answer (score 1):

Probably I do not quite understand the problem, but if you want solutions which would be valid for all t, then I would first eliminate it from the equations above. Unfortunately SolveAlways[] don't work in this case. 
Still You can calculate GroebnerBasis and eliminate t like this

```
gb = GroebnerBasis[{x == 
    1/18 (-6 b - t + 12 y + Sqrt[t] Sqrt[12 b + t + 12 y]), 
   y == 1/18 (-6 b + t + 12 x - Sqrt[t] Sqrt[-12 b + t - 12 x])}, {x, 
   y}, {t}]
```

And then solve obtained equations

```
Solve[(# == 0) & /@ gb, {x, y}]
```

> {{y -> -2 b - x}, {x -> -b, y -> -b}}

This gives relation between y and x, which should be valid for any t.